# SP2010 Joined List View Builder: An Impossible Task?

Tags: 2010, list-view, joined-view

Imagine 2 very large lists: Tickets and Assignments. Assignments is a separate list because the client wants to categorize the assignment type, like BA and PM, plus have fields for estimated/actual hours.

The challenge: A solution that will:

1. Mimic OOB SP view
2. Show the ticket and related assignment data
3. Allow the end user to create the view with OOB SP-like UI
4. Handle group by options*

*** Item 4 is proving to be the biggest issue!!  I've been able to generate an acceptable view with web service calls via jQuery. But if the grouping is collapsed by default it just doesn't work.
What am I missing?

Comment: How are the two lists joined? Why can't you just use OOB view?

Comment: In SP2010 expand/collapse function is not just visual appearance, but includes some asynchronous loading. If a group is collapsed by default, the items will be queried only when you expand the group. So when you run your jquery code, items actually do not exist on the page

Comment: It one to many, one ticket may have many assignments of different categories. The assignments list has the "lookup" to the ticket list. Client wants all views generated from the ticket list. This needs a master to related items view. Do you know how to get that OOB?

Comment: Tim:  exactly. The jQuery works if the view is expanded by default. The solution needs to handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SPServices to get the data you want and construct two javascript objects and display using jquery. If you have 3rd party control plugins like KendoUI you could simply attach the grid controls to your return objects. Since the grids support filtering, sorting, and grouping, you would only have to skin them to look closer to sharepoint.